# gitの過去の履歴は自動的に削除されるか

Tags: git

git でたくさん何年にもわたってコミットしていくと、すごくたくさんのコミットがたまると思うのですけど、
古いデータが自動的に消失することはあるのですか？（例えば、アップルのタイムカプセルのように。）

Answer (score 5):

gitに限らず、履歴のコミットが自動的に消失するようなバージョン管理システムはないと思います。

gitでは、存在するタグ、ブランチの履歴コミットが時間経過で削除されることはありません。
存在するタグ、ブランチから到達できないコミットは一定期間(例えば45日)経ったタイミングでgitコマンドを使用した時に、ガベージコレクションされ削除されますが、
普通の使い方をしている限り、この自動削除される機構について意識する必要はないでしょう。
詳しく知りたい場合は、`git gc`や`git reflog`について調べてみてください。